# Illustrator: save for web as PNG gives me a sliced version

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png

Attempting to save a file in PNG-24 format with the `Save for Web` command in Illustrator. This creates a new folder called `Images` with several PNG files instead of just one, each file being a slice of the entire image.

Comment: Edit output settings was removed in CS6. Since then, I don't believe we've had control over the save for web command (which is deprecated). As zeethreepio mentioned, I would try exporting as a PNG using one of the other two export options.

Comment: Is it possible you're using 'Export for Screens' instead of 'Save for Web'?

Comment: Do you need (or have) slices in your document? If not, go to `Object` >> `Slice` >> `Delete All`. Then save for web again. Alternatively, use one of the newer options for saving images like `Asset Export` or `Export...` (as png) or `Export for Screens`. If that does not work, open in Photoshop and save from there? Hard to say much more without more info.

Answer (score -1):

1). First Select which slice you want,

[image]

2). Select save for web option and Select Export Menu and Select as Selected Slice, and Save

[image]

3). Show in Folder Every Slice is Separate.

[image]